# PropertyConfigurator.configure() (log4j 1.2.4) replacement in log4j 2.16

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are using property configuration in our java project having log4j 1.x version. Clients asked to upgrade to 2.16 from 1.x version. I replaced the jar file from log4j 1.2.4 to log4j 2.16. The only error I got was with

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

In the main function, i used
PropertyConfigurator.configure(property.getProperty("LOG_PATH"));

PropertyConfigurator is the class available in log4j 1.2.4 jar.
Since i replaced it with log4j 2.16 jar, this PropertyConfigurator Class is not available.
My question is : 1) What should i do inorder to get rid of this error.
2) What is the alternate class available in log4j 2.16 which replaces PropertyConfigurator class.

Totally we are using property files only. Not xml.Please help me with this guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below Log4J2 documentation
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#reconfig_from_code

Note: make sure to rename your log4j.xml/properties file to log4j2.xml/properties

Example:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

public void configureLog4j() throws IOException
{
  String path = getLog4jConfigFilePath();
  File file = new File(path);
  if (file.exists())
  {
    LoggerContext context  = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
        context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
  }else
  {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: The docs look like this still requires an xml base configuration, however the OP mentions they are NOT using xml based configs, but properties based configs. Does this solution support both? Have you tried it?